# std::priority_queue with iterators to elements of std::map - invalid heap

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I haven't pasted all code because it could be too much complicated. I'll try to write about my problem first.

I try to implement some algorithm. I need container (key-value) with with access by key (like `std::map`) and I need to fast access to get (and remove) element with maximum value.

So I use `std::map<key, value> myMap` and I have `std::priority_queue<std::map<key, value>::iterator> myQueue`.

```
    typedef std::map<cv::Point, double>::iterator mapIter;

    class mycomparison
    {
        public:
        bool operator() (mapIter lhs, mapIter rhs) const
        {
            return lhs->second > rhs->second; // (*)
        }
    };

    std::priority_queue<mapIter, std::vector<mapIter>, mycomparison> myQueue;

     // I fill `myQueue` with iterator to every element of `myMap` ...

    while (!myQueue.empty())
    {
        mapIter iter = myQueue.top();
        // ...
        // ...
        if (myMap[key1] > myMap[iter->first] + someValue)
            myMap[key1] = myMap[iter->first] + someValue; // (**)
        myQueue.pop();
    }
```

I have problem with debugging it. I have an error during `myQueue.pop()` - `Invalid heap`. When I commented line with (**). There is no error.

What is wrong? Is it unsafe operation?

Or maybe mistake is in another line?

How about `comparision` (*)? When I return `return lhs->second > rhs->second;` Everything looks OK. But I need > operation.

I couldn't understand why there is an error. I spent many hours. Any idea?

I think it's all my important code for this question...

Comment: +1 : Very well-asked question.

Comment: `myMap[key1] = myMap[key2];` may add or overwrite - no elimination of elements in the loop - Hence, there is no way to answer this question - Maybe put `Q.pop();` in front of `}`

Comment: @Dieter Thanks for reply. I've added some code. Q.pop() is before `}`. It has always been. I've made a mistake in this post. In my code Q.pop() is in right place. I've edited it here.

Comment: And `myMap[iter->first]` really should just be `iter->second`.

Comment: But either way, you really need to create a test set that someone else could compile. There's likely not enough information here to determine your issue.

Comment: @Bill, thanks for interest. I'll try to prepare some code to run.

Comment: Why dont you use a set ?

Comment: @ rgbimbochamp . Set? Instead of priority_queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that the assignment to the values in the map causes the heap condition to become violated: since the elements you are storing in the priority queue are not the values but only reference the values, changing the elements can break the necessary conditions! Just because you change the key of an element doesn't mean that the priority queue will rearrange the structure of the priority queue.

It seems you are trying to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm which requires updating the key of a node when it is detected that there is a shorter path to an already reached node. To deal with these updates you'll need to somehow reference the node in the in the priority queue which needs to be updated. Conventionally a Fibonacci-heap is used to implement this algorithms efficiently which also has the advantage that it is node based rather than array based: elements in a Fibonacci-heap stay put in memory making it easy to keep a reference to the node which can then be adjusted.

A similar logic can be implemented with a d-heap but `std::priority_queue<T>` doesn't provide this functionality. The approach to use a d-heap with fixed node positions is to store an auxiliary array with pointers to the nodes in the d-heap which provides the keys used for updates. When elements in the d-heap are moved the corresponding pointers in the auxiliary array are also updated. These updates slow down the processing substantially which is the reason they are not done when they are not needed, e.g., for `std::priority_queue<T>` which can be used for heap-sort.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. It's The shortest path by Dijkstra. And your answer clear everything... 
I have no idea how to good implement this algorithm. :(

Comment: Thanks for adding more informations. I'll try to implement this.

Comment: I know it could be not good operation. But is there any possibility to "update" priority_queue? If `myMap[key1] = myMap[iter->first] + someValue;` is called I'd like to update my priority queue. Is it possible?

Comment: The algorithm used by `std::priority_queue<..>`  supports updating an elements priority. However, the class template doesn't expose an interface to do so ([Boost](http://boost.org) has an implementation which does). The operations are normally call "sift-up" and " sift-down". The implementation is fairly steaight forward. The biggest issue is location the position of the element which needs to be updated: d-heaps use an arsay and elements change their location inside.